# Como recupero el valor de la consulta SELECT MAX en sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, sql-server

Hago una consulta que me devuelva el valor máximo de una columna pero no sé cómo recuperar ese valor, para tratarlo.

```
$param_nid = array(&$Maximo, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT);
$sql       = "SELECT MAX('ID') AS Maximo FROM PEDIDOS";
$stmt      = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $sql, $param_nid);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    echo $Maximo;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Como bien explica el Manual de PHP, [`sqlsrv_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-query.php) devuelve un recurso con los datos o bien `false` en caso de error.

> Returns a statement resource on success and FALSE if an error
> occurred.

Para leer ese recurso con los datos existen los métodos `fetch` que son varios.

El que más se suele usar es [`sqlsrv_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php).

Cuando se esperan varias filas, se suele abrir un bucle para ir moviendo el puntero del recurso y sacando los datos con el método ´fetch_`, pero para el caso de tu consulta, dado que devuelve sólo una fila, no hace falta abrir bucle.

La lectura puede ser así:

```
$param_nid = array(&$Maximo, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT);
$sql       = "SELECT MAX('ID') AS Maximo FROM PEDIDOS";
$stmt      = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $sql, $param_nid);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $row["Maximo"];
}
```

Aquí, `$row` será el recurso con el resultado, al aplicar la constante `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` los datos serán organizados como array asociativo por cada columna => valor, por lo que haciendo `$row["Maximo"]` obtendrás el dato.

A este método se le pueden aplicar otras banderas, según quieras organizar los resultados. En el enlace del Manual está todo explicado.